# How to work with DTOs in Controller of WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm a bit confused how to use DTOs in my WebAPI controllers. I'm using the Database first concept of Entity Framework. The following Entity Data Model was generated:

```
//Generated class by EDM:
public partial class Address
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Address()
        {
            this.Member = new HashSet<Member>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> Street_Number { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Zip { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Member> Member { get; set; }
    }
```

To use Data Annotations I need to define a `AddressDTO` because every time when I need to modify the EDM the data model will generated again and the Data Annotations are lost.

So next, I defined the `AddressDTO`:

```
public class AddressDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100,ErrorMessage="The max. length of the street name is 100 characters.")]
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> Street_Number { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Nullable<decimal> Zip { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"[a-z,A-Z]",ErrorMessage="Only characters are allowed.")]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
```

And the controller looks like the code below:

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/address")]
    public class AddressController : ApiController
    {
        private PersonEntities db = new PersonEntities();

        // GET: api/Address
        [HttpGet]
        [ResponseType(typeof(AddressDTO))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            var addressList = await db.Address.ToListAsync();

            return Ok(addressList);
        }
     }
```

When I'm starting the RestAPI to display the result in browser, I always get the following json result:

```
[
    {
        "Member": [ ],
        "Id": 1,
        "Street": "Example Street",
        "Street_Number": 1,
        "Zip": 12345.0,
        "City": "New York",
        "Country": "USA" 
    },...
]
```

But I need the following desired result:

```
[
        {
            "Street": "Example Street",
            "Street_Number": 1,
            "Zip": 12345.0,
            "City": "New York",
            "Country": "USA" 
        },...
    ]
```

Has anyone an idea how could I resolve that?

Comment: Create wrapper class which have only properties you want expose to the API

Comment: You don't need to create a different model just because you want to use some data annotations attribute. You can simply use [MetadataTypeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Could you give me an example code?

Comment: Your new edit simply means you don't need `Id` and `Member` properties in your `AddressDTO` model.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yes for example I need only some attributes. That was the intention why I created a DTO.

Comment: So just remove unused properties from `AddressDTO` and shape the result using `Select`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Do I always need to use LINQ-statements like `.Select()` in my controller?

Comment: Yes, but you can make the linq shorter. Also you can use object mappers like Automapper as mentioned in an answer.

Answer (score 8):

Your new edit simply means you don't need `Id` and `Member` properties in your `AddressDTO` model. And yo should shape the result to be a `List<AddressDTO>` while you are returning `List<Address>`.

So just remove unused properties from `AddressDTO` and then shape the result by selecting new `AddressDTO` and setting properties:

```
var result = db.Address.Select(x=> new AddressDTO()
                                   { 
                                       Street = x.Id, 
                                       Street_Number = x.Street_Number,
                                       City = x.City,
                                       Country = x.Country
                                   }).ToListAsync();
```

If you want to make the linq shorter, you can add such constructor to `AddressDTO`:

```
public AddressDTO(Address x)
{
    Street = x.Id;
    Street_Number = x.Street_Number;
    City = x.City;
    Country = x.Country;
}
```

Then in controller:

```
var result = db.Address.Select(x=> new AddressDTO(x)).ToListAsync();
```

Also in a large project, you can rely on some object mappers like auto mapper as mentioned in an answer.

Comment: do I need to create an another partial class `Address`?

Comment: Thank you for your support! I will try it later and give you a feedback :)

Comment: Sorryyy I had no time. I will try it next week and then give you a feedback ok?

Answer (score 7):

Use a library like [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) to handle your needs.

Then you just need to modify the following line to this for example:

```
var addressList = await Mapper.Map<IList<AddressDto>>(db.Address.ToListAsync());
```

This will convert your Address list to an AddressDto list where you can control what gets converted or not so not to pass Members for example to your view. And Automapper will automatically know what to convert if the field names are the same.